# why does helm uninstall not trigger events for python kubernetes watch?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart which has some deployments, configmaps and secrets.
When i run helm uninstall, i see that the pods,deployments, configmaps and secrets are removed.

But I also have another namespace (not in the helm chart) and a pod runs a python script:

```py
config.load_incluster_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
w = watch.Watch()
for event in w.stream(v1.list_secret_for_all_namespaces):
utc_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        iso_format_string = utc_time.isoformat()
        print(iso_format_string+ " : Event: %s %s %s" % (event['type'], event['object'].kind, event['object'].metadata.name))
```

There are no events related to the secret deletion in my watch. However, when i manually delete or edit the secret using kubectl commands, i see the events.

Does helm uninstall work differently?

Comment: helm also uses kubernetes client libraries to install, update the resources. So there should not be any difference between doing via kubectl and helm.
Just check if you have some settings are something in kubernetes cluster or helm.
You can also check kube-apiserver logs - you may get some hints